# bitcoin-cli is not using port specified in config

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest

I have setup a bitcoin node in regtest mode with custom config and datadir.

I start bittcoind with command:

```
 bitcoind -conf=bitcoin-demo.conf  -regtest  -datadir="testdatabtc" -daemon
```

My bitcoin-demo.conf looks like:

```
regtest=1
server=1
rpcuser=alice
rpcpassword=hello
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
# Options only for regtest
[regtest]
rpcport=3133
```

I am able to connect access my node using curl command

```
curl --user alice:hello --data '{"method":"getblockchaininfo","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3133
```

But when I try to  access the same commands using **bitcoin-cli**, it tries to connect to port 8332, even when I specify the config file.

```
bitcoin-cli -conf="bitcoin-demo.conf"  getblockchaininfo
```

This command produces error:

> error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332

This works if I specify the port and auth as command line argument:

```
bitcoin-cli -conf="bitcoin-demo.conf" -rpcport="3133" -rpcuser="alice" -rpcpassword="hello"  getblockchaininfo
```

Above command works fine. But the question is

**Why bitcoin-cli does not read these arguments from the config file?**

Comment: Did you try just `port=3133`

Comment: Maybe, try to generate rpcauth with https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/share/rpcauth